# Why does this work with Firefox but not Chrome or IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code that runs when the process_2banner button is clicked on a html page. This code does what is supposed to do when using Firefox. When using Chrome and Internet Explorer the ajax code is called but the div spinner_block does not show/hide as the code intends to. 
Strangely enough it works if I open firebug in Chrome and place a breakpoint  right before the ajax call (after the `.css("display","block")` statement. The spinner_box `<div>` shows, and then after the ajax call returns, it hides.

Can you see what is wrong here? 
Thank you very much!
Andres

```
$('#process_2banner').on("click",function() {
    var postdata = "lead_id="+rowId;   //needs to include the pidm of the user clicking the button
    $('#spinner_box').css("display","block");
    $('#spinner_box').html('Wait, we are processing the record..');
    $('#spinner_box').css("display","block");
    $.ajax({type: "POST",
        url: "insert_srwordpress.php",
        data:postdata,
        success:function(result) {
            if (result.isOk == false) { 
                alert('Some error occurred while writing Banner') } 
            else { 
                $('#spinner_box').hide();
            }
        },
        async: false});
});
```

Comment: `async: false` , nothing good comes from Synchronous AJAX.

Comment: You are right, That was the problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

The response result is an string in format JSON?
May you need parse the JSON before use it?

Example:

```
var jData = $.parseJSON(result);

if (jData.isOk === false) {

  }
```